# Excel VBA: Remove ListBox Item if in Array

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim libRng As Range, item As Long
Dim refArrCheck As Variant, refArr As Variant

Set libRng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:F1000")
refArr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BA1")

For Each refArrCheck In refArr
    For Each cell In libRng.Cells
        For item = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If Me.ListBox1.Column(0, item) = cell.Value And cell.Value = refArrCheck Then
              Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem (item)
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next refArrCheck
```

Essentially I am trying to tell Excel to look through **libRng** and compare it with the array **refArr** if there is any matches, remove **item** from ListBox. **refArr** values are items listed in the ListBox. The following code seems to "work" but it does not work properly in that when I run it, it only removes 1 item that matches when there are more that match.

Is my 3rd For Loop or If statement wrong? Also would it matter if some cells in **libRng** are blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a lot of unnecessary looping and checking. There are native worksheet functions that can search whole ranges at once to determine existence of a value.

```
Dim libRng As Range, refArr As Range, itm As Long

Set libRng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:F1000")
Set refArr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BA1")

For itm = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If CBool(Application.CountIf(libRng, Me.ListBox1.Column(0, itm))) And _
       CBool(Application.CountIf(refArr, Me.ListBox1.Column(0, itm))) Then
            Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem (itm)
    End If
Next
```

The [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) canot use an array with a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) but it can with a [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca).

Comment: Much cleaner version then mines. The real problem with my code was I had my libRng set wrong and that was the reason why (I think) it didn't work as I expected. Overall, I like yours much better. Thanks!